# Make a .row a Bootstrap's affix

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm getting the hang of Bootstrap's affix but I have some difficulty because I am trying to use it to use `position: fixed` on a `.row`.

More precisely, what I am trying to do:

- have a sum/total line always visible at the bottom of a scrolling list;
- once you get to the bottom of the list, the sum/total line scrolls up to let the user see the content below (in my case, only the footer common across the rest of the site).

Here is a quick case that tries to reproduce my situation: https://jsfiddle.net/cyChop/wf8smye9/

As you'll see, the affix line displays well when you get to the bottom (`.affix-bottom`) but does not take the proper positions when in `position: fixed` (`.affix-top` and `.affix`).

I feel like I'm close and need only some light tinkering with the classes and CSS but I'm having difficulties finding out the clean and general solution.

Answer (score 2):

You have to apply width of `.affix` like 100% or something.

Because when you set `position:fixed` then you have to apply width of that div.

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/wf8smye9/3/

Comment: You can also share the link within the answer.

Comment: Hi @Cherish! Yeah, I tried the width, but 100% was too much. I see you used 91.3, but this works only for one size of screen (resize your window, and you'll see it's off again). I am looking for a way to determine this precisely (possibly from Bootstrap's variables). Relative width won't work because I'd need something like `100% - 30px` (to compensate for the margins), which is not possible in CSS as far as I know of.

Comment: You can also try this

width: calc(100% - 30px);

Comment: @Cherish Sorry, I didn't see your latest comment. I didn't know of `calc`, but thank you! It indeed appears to be the way to go! See [my updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wf8smye9/4/) which appears to work. Maybe you can update your answer based on this so that it includes all useful elements (styles, container chain, ...; or I can propose an edit). This way, I can accept your answer and give you the credit you deserve (AFAIK, answers should be self-sufficient, without need for the next ones to skim the comments).

Comment: `calc` works in this simple case, but not when the div is inside more complex parents though.

Comment: Yes, but whenever we're use position:fixed that time width is required.